# MSSQL 2016 - Restore SSISDB from MSSQL 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016, ssms

On "MSSQL 2016 (SP2-CU11) (KB4527378)" I created empty SSISDB. After that I restored SSISDB from "MSSQL 2012 (SP4) (KB4018073)" to "MSSQL 2016 (SP2-CU11) (KB4527378)" On DB I set owner to sa and version to Compatible Level 2016(130).

On Integration Services I want to do upgrade. I click on Database Upgrade and I get error:

> The system cannot find the file specified (System)

Program Location:

```
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.UITasks.ActionHandler.PerformAction(String actionMoniker, IContext context)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Some screenshots

[image]

[image]

I tried to run wizard from disk a I got error:

[image]

Comment: Are you running SSMS and the SSIS Database Upgrade Wizard locally on the server? "The wizard can only upgrade the database on a local server instance." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/catalog/ssis-catalog?view=sql-server-2016#upgrade-the-ssis-catalog-ssisdb

Comment: Yes, I am running upgrade locally on server over RDP.

Comment: Not sure.  But if you need a workaround, you can always run the SQL 2016 upgrade on a 2012 instance hosting that SSISDB, or use SSDT to upgrade and re-deploy your packages to 2016.  per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/upgrade-integration-services?view=sql-server-2016

Comment: On server I use SSMS v 18.00

Comment: Did you also backup and restore the master key for the SSISDB database?

Comment: No, I know password for ssisdb. In manual I read that is not nessesery. I will try it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to start with a fresh SSISDB on SQL 2016 then migrate your projects from 2k12 to 2k16 one by one ?

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into the same problem after restoring the SSISDB database from a lower SQL version to a higher SQL version; I've ran into:

- SSIDDB Upgrade not working or erroring out on the "sql version doesn't match"
- Validating packages erroring on customized_logging_levels not existing
- all other errors one can encounter...

I noticed the newer SSISDB has more tables, views and different stored procedures. However there's a fairly easy solution, although unconventional.

1. restore the SSISDB on the "new" SQL (already Integration Services Catalog Enabled)
2. sp_changedbowner 'sa'
3. open master key decryption by password = 'yourkeyinserthere'
   Alter Master Key Add encryption by Service Master Key
4. EXEC sp_change_users_login 'update_one', '##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobUser##','##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin##'
5. ALTER DATABASE [SSISDB] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130 (or the one you need)
6. Install a CU higher then your current one

Installing the CU does the SSISDB upgrade and you can check that by looking at the table internal.catalog_properties. It will have a line "upgrade from".

Also, what if you are already on the latest CU? Well, uninstall your last CU and reinstall it. That works too.